# How to remove None rows from numpy array of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array looking like this:

```
[array([268.95504761,  -4.17598009, 404.12548828])
array([268.9979248 ,  -4.15205622, 404.09713745])
array([269.00808716,  -4.14346504, 404.07214355])
array([280.63632202,  -8.46781635, 398.50079346])
None 
None 
array([281.69018555,  -9.98347282, 390.9984436 ])]
```

How do I remove the None lines? All method I found assumed the regular case of a normal 2D array containing some None elements.

Comment: What methods have you tries?  Remember this is a 1d object dtype array (or a list], not a 2d numeric array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[elem for elem in my_list if elem is not None]
```

Simple list-comprehension? Correct me if I misunderstood you :-)

Comment: `elem is not None`

Comment: For comparison with singletons (like `None`), `elem is not None` is the proper way to check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe

Comment: The None-type object is a great thing isn't it (;

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I need! Sometimes you just don't see the easy solutions :D